# What is the nginx equivalent of this htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I'm new to nginx and having a hard time trying to convert this htaccess file into readable nginx logic:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The farthest I came up with was this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?uri=$args;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need both URI and query string arguments, $uri and $args in nginx.
Try this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?uri=$uri&$args;
}
```